# GStreamer External Clock

Tags: synchronization, gstreamer, clock

I am using GStreamer in my media player application to play TS files. Though I am able to play audio & video, not able to use PCR for synchronization.

When googled, found the documentation for [gst_pipeline_use_clock()](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/stable/GstPipeline.html) and used the same in my code.
However, it is not setting the clock and giving some random values [when clock time is retrieved using: gst_clock_get_time() ]

This is how, I am setting the PCR clock: Is there anything I am missing?

```
GstClock stPCRClock = {0};
stPCRClock.last_time = (GstClockTime)pcrInfo; //pcrInfo is the PCR value: 32-bit
gst_pipeline_use_clock(pipeline, &stPCRClock);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Kranti

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet does not make any sense at all (you created a static clock that does not tick). Please read what clocks do. If you have troubles with A/V sync for particular files, discuss this on the #gstreamer irc channel or file a bug. Ideally make such a problematic video file available to the developers.

Comment: I am not claiming it is a bug at GStreamer Side. Problem is, I am not able to understand how to set the external clock?

We receive clock time from broadcaster at regular intervals. Doubt is how to feed this to gstreamer and instruct it to use this clock as reference?

Comment: You will need to implement a GstClock subclass, using the timing information you have. GstClock is not a simple struct, it is a GObject.